# Stateful JSON Parser for Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, stateful

I have a Ruby server that reads from a flat file every 1 second or so and this flat file is constantly being updated with new data every 1 second or so by another server. This flat file is essentially a JSON file. The thing is, I don't wanna read the entire file over and over again. Rather, I want the ruby server to figure out which of the content is new and read only those portions. So I'm guessing I'm searching for a stateful JSON parser for Ruby. Since I'm very new to Ruby, I'm not familiar with such a library. Could anybody suggest something that might work in such a situation?

Comment: do you mean you want to be able to parse incrementally as you receive data ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung: "which of the content is new" - I don't think he's talking about append-only file.

Comment: @FrederickCheung: Like Sergio mentioned, I want to read only the new content. I want to be able to keep note of where the previous read operation on that file ended and resume reading from there. That's the issue. I'm not able to figure out how to do that. Also, I'm writing a daemon that will periodically clean up the file by deleting earlier json strings once a threshold is reached. So that adds to the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found yajl-ruby a few mins ago and I'm checking that out now. It seems to be the answer. I'm not sure yet. I'll check it out and let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How's the format of the file? Because if it *is* a JSON file, then

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as "stateful JSON parser". Stateful (as in "stateful server") means that server (or parser) maintains some state between requests (parsings). But you'll have to read and parse the whole file anyway, so why complicate stuff?

If the file is small, just parse it whole every time. If the file is ginormous, use a database instead.

Comment: "But you'll have to read and parse the whole file anyway". That's my issue. Is there any way to not do that everytime? Can a parser record where it stopped and resume from there the next time? I'm hoping there's a parser that can do that?

Comment: So, the other process, is it only appending to the file?

Comment: And yes, the file is large. It will contain several thousand JSON strings and I'm trying to do everything in real time. That's why I don't wanna keep reading the whole file everytime. I could use a database, but I'm plugging this module with another large one and that one writes to flat files. Changing that is pretty complex and it's not a road I wanna take. That's why I'm trying to solve the problem this way. Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the other module keeps appending to the file and the module I'm writing keeps reading from it.